# Android studio doesnt detecting my android device

Tags: android, windows-7, android-studio-3.3

I am using Android Studio 3.3.When i connect my device,Samsung Galaxy Grand2,the pc has detects it but the Android studio doesnt!!!

I have installed the drivers and updates it properly.The Debugging is enabled in my device.I have tried both PTP and MTP.But when i click the 'Run' button of the android studio,it will not show any devices.I pressed the 'Don't see your Device' link in the same window.It shows my device in the first step in the list of attached devices.But,proceeding further,finally it will shows no device is connected.What can i do?please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Plug in** your android device click on **run button** and then click on **troubleshoot**. This will open **Assistant** on right side of the application and follow the steps to **restart ADB server**. 
Hope this will help you, pal.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.But I have done this already.But still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use the below link Install & Read Instructions. **USB OEM DRIVERS.**
and Restart Computer.

- Link

[OEM DRIVERS](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb)

-try ADB Driver
[link](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.But its already done previously.But didnt get the result.

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't work, you may need to setup new rom. I had to do that for my Samsung tablet. I tried s8 and j7 too they didn't work as the others.

You may wanna take a look to https://forum.xda-developers.com/ for that.